# Changing Video's rotation metadata without rotating video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rotation, metadata, transpose

I have two Videos. One is from front camera and one is from back camera. When I concatenate these two. one gets vertically inverted in merged file. Video taken from front camera having rotation metadata 270. And Video taken from back camera having rotation metadata 90. While concatenation one gets inverted, while I don't want. Please help....

Comment: Interesting, Don't think this can be solved without re-encoding. The stream rotation metadata is stored globally in the MP4 index.

Comment: yes, it would be better if someway we can only update metadata. But could you please tell me that way?

Comment: Hello @ArshdeepSingh Have u solved this. I am getting same problem.

Comment: @KarandeepAtwal, no dear, I haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: @ArshdeepSingh for front cam video i reencode it first thn i concatenate ..it takes little more time. But that's only option i was left with.

Comment: It's been a long time, but that problem still exists, is there a solution within the same concat command?